# The font becomes thinner after editing

Tags: fonts, font-face, glyph

I want remove unnecessary symbols from font «SFUI Text Regular». File size 104kb.

1. FontForge

Tried use [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/). Deleted ~50% symbols. Save font. Tried use on the website. Result: the file size has decreased (104kb > 35kb), but **the letters are thinner than originally**. (i am sure, that this is wasn't system font, it's same font, but thinner)

2. Fonttools

Tried use [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools), [pyftsubset](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subset/index.html?highlight=pyftsubset) command.

```
pyftsubset font.woff --output-file=font2.woff --unicodes-file=symbols.txt
```

symbols.txt — list of needed symbols in format U+XXXX. Checked few times for truth.

Deleted ~50% symbols. Got needed font file. File size **increased** (104kb > 110kb). And this font give me **originally** thickness of letters, but i need decrease file size.

2.1. Converting

Tried convert woff to woff2 ([convertio](https://convertio.co/) service). Decreased file size. Tried font file: thinner letters. Tried convert woff2 to woff back. Decreased file size. Result: thinner letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried few more programs and services for this.

[FontCreator Pro](https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator) helped decide problem.
No specific settings. I just opened it, deleted characters, saved it.